# How to loop with a reaction embed menu

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: Learning to make a proper help menu for my discord.py bot by having the `ctx.message.author` react to the message with the reactions given. The bot checks if they've been reacted to, then edits the message. If the `ctx.message.author` un-reacts, it goes back to the first menu (menuu).

**Problem(s)**: I'm not sure how to loop through this until the `timeout` runs out. I'm also not sure how to check if the user un-reacts to the message.

**Error(s)**: No errors.

````py
@client.command()
async def menuu(ctx):
    #what reaction goes where menuu
    menuu = discord.Embed(title="menuu", color=0x8d78d9)
    menuu.add_field(name="Topics: ", value="React with <:oneone:772681764321099827>", inline=False)
    menuu.add_field(name="Games: ", value="React with <:twotwo:772681764271423528>", inline=False)
    menuu.add_field(name="Misc: ", value="React with <:threethree:772681763939024897>", inline=False)
    menuu.set_footer(text=f"Ensure you drink some water today, you're doing so well {ctx.message.author}")
    #topics menuu
    topics = discord.Embed(title="Topics", color=0x8d78d9)
    topics.add_field(name="`bl!topic`: ", value="Friend makers and ice breakers", inline=False)
    topics.add_field(name="`bl!debate`: ", value="menuu not complete sorry haha")
    topics.set_footer(text="Never forget to believe in yourself, because I do!")
    #game menuu
    games = discord.Embed(title="Games", color=0x8d78d9)
    games.add_field(name="`nothing here`: ", value="Technically there is but still", inline=False)
    games.set_footer(text="Eat some food, take a nap, good luck on the journey ahead")
    #misc menuu
    misc = discord.Embed(title="Misc", color=0x8d78d9)
    misc.add_field(name="`miscmimscimc`: ", value="aeaeaeaeaeaeeae", inline=False)
    misc.set_footer(text="You look lovely today, you're rocking this look")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=menuu)#send message
    #add reactions things
    await msg.add_reaction("<:oneone:772681764321099827>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:twotwo:772681764271423528>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:threethree:772681763939024897>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:stop:773054889685024768>")

    try:
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["<:oneone:772681764321099827>","<:twotwo:772681764271423528>","<:threethree:772681763939024897>"]
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:oneone:772681764321099827>":
            await msg.edit(embed=topics)
            await msg.remove_reaction("<:oneone:772681764321099827>", ctx.message.author)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:twotwo:772681764271423528>":
            await msg.edit(embed=games)
            await msg.remove_reaction("<:twotwo:772681764271423528>", ctx.message.author)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:threethree:772681763939024897>":
            await msg.edit(embed=misc)
            await msg.remove_reaction("<:threethree:772681763939024897>", ctx.message.author)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:stop:773054889685024768>":
            await msg.edit(embed=menuu)
            await msg.remove_reaction("<:stop:773054889685024768>", ctx.message.author)       
            
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Time has run out, message no work now")
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an easy enough to use 'book-manager'. If you put all of your menuus into a list called pages you can use this function:

```
async def createbook(bot, ctx, title, pages, **kwargs):

        header = kwargs.get("header", "") # String
        results = kwargs.get("results", 0) # Int
        
        pagenum = 1

        def get_results():
            results_min = (pagenum - 1) * 8 + 1
            if pagenum == len(pages): results_max = results
            else: results_max = pagenum * 8
            return f"Showing {results_min} - {results_max} results out of {results}"

        pagemax = len(pages)
        if results:
            header = get_results()
            if len(pages) == 0: pagemax = 1

        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=f"{header}\n\n{pages[pagenum - 1]}", colour=0xF42F42)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {pagenum}/{pagemax}", icon_url=fboturl)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        
        await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
        await msg.add_reaction("➡")
        
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["⬅️", "➡"]
    
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 60, check=check)
                await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅️":
                    pagenum -= 1
                    if pagenum < 1: pagenum = len(pages)
                        
                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "➡":
                    pagenum += 1
                    if pagenum > len(pages): pagenum = 1

                header = get_results() if results else header
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅️" or str(reaction.emoji) == "➡":
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=f"{header}\n\n{pages[pagenum - 1]}", colour=0xF42F42)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {pagenum}/{len(pages)}", icon_url=fboturl)
                    await msg.edit(embed=embed)
            except:
                header = get_results() if results else header
                embed = discord.Embed(title="FBot Server Status", description=f"{header}\n\n{pages[pagenum - 1]}", colour=0xF42F42)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Request timed out", icon_url=fboturl)
                await msg.edit(embed=embed)
                break
```

(I avoid using numbers purely because books with more than 10 pages are annoying to manage)

Answer (score 0):

So after a really long time of trial and error, I have figured out my own method based off of Judev1's create-book thing. I incorporated the way the page number changes, as well as the `wait_for` and time out things.

````py
@client.command(aliases=["help"])
async def menuu(ctx):
    #first just giving all the embeds a purpose and a place to exist
    user = ctx.author
    menuu = discord.Embed(title="Help Menuu", color=0x8d78d9)
    menuu.add_field(name="How to navigate : ", value="```Use the arrow reactions below to navigate this menuu```", inline=False)
    menuu.add_field(name="How to invite bot : ", value="```Use bl!invite to invite this bot and join our support server!```", inline=True)
    menuu.set_footer(text=f"Ensure you drink some water today, you're doing so well {ctx.message.author}")
    #topics menuu
    topics = discord.Embed(title="Topics", color=0x8d78d9)
    topics.add_field(name="bl!topic : ", value="```Friend makers and ice breakers```", inline=False)
    topics.add_field(name="bl!debate : ", value="```Sends a debate topic (Trigger Warning: Some topics may trigger certain individuals. Please tread with caution when using this command)```", inline=False)
    topics.add_field(name="bl!wyr : ", value="```Would you rather questions```", inline = False)
    topics.add_field(name="bl!place : ", value="```So many places in the world, so little time```", inline = True)
    topics.set_footer(text="Never forget to believe in yourself, because I do!")
    #game menuu
    games = discord.Embed(title="Games", color=0x8d78d9)
    games.add_field(name=f"bl!powpow `@blitz` : ", value="```Who will win? You, or that person you mentioned?```", inline=False)
    games.add_field(name=f"bl!battle `@blitz` : ", value="```Basically powpow but less work```", inline=True)
    games.set_footer(text="Eat some food, take a nap, good luck on the journey ahead")
    #pics menuu
    pics = discord.Embed(title="Picture Things:tm:", color=0x8d78d9)
    pics.add_field(name="bl!avatar `@blitz` : ", value="```Get the profile picture of the mentioned person```", inline=False)
    pics.add_field(name="bl!hug `@blitz` : ", value="```Hugs, many hug gifs :)```", inline= True)
    pics.add_field(name="bl!slap `@blitz` : ", value="```Slap whoever you want without the pain```", inline=False)
    pics.set_footer(text="You look lovely today, you're rocking this look")
    ##send message##
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=menuu)
    
    pages = 1 #page it's currently on
    left = "<a:totheleft:767541559440572427>" #left arrow reaction
    right = "<a:totheright:767541574287884309>" #right arrow reaction

    await msg.add_reaction(left) #add reaction to send menuu
    await msg.add_reaction(right) #and again

    def check(reaction, user): #checking if user is author and the reaction is either left or right (as defined earlier)
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [left, right]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 120, check=check)
            await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == left:
                pages = pages - 1
                if pages < 1:
                    pages = 4 #if pages is less than 1, go straight to 4

            if str(reaction.emoji) == right:
                pages = pages + 1
                if pages > 4:
                    pages = 1 #if pages is more than 4, go back to 1
                #if this is the page number, edit so it's this embed instead
            if pages == 1:
                await msg.edit(embed=menuu)

            elif pages == 2:
                await msg.edit(embed=topics)

            elif pages == 3:
                await msg.edit(embed=games)

            elif pages == 4:
                await msg.edit(embed=pics)

        except: #timeout error handling
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Run command again to use", description="Have a good day {ctx.author.display_name}! `bl!menuu`")
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
            break
````