# Waiting for command author's reaction to edit to the help category page

Tags: python, discord.py

```
message=await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, after reacting to an emoji below the message will be edited to your choosen category)

        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')



        message = await client.wait_for('on_reaction_add', timeout= 10, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

        if message.reaction_add == '':
            await ctx.send("You reacted!")
```

Im making a command to use the help page and it edits the pre-existing help message to the category the user chooses that corresponds to the emoji they reacted for.

I have used a way that has no checks which annoys other people if they happen to react with those emojis to another message, is there are way to make a check similar to what I have already done or close to, where the message of help can be edited to the page the user wants and only works if they used the command specifically for the author that can use the emojis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py-rewrite wait\_for() how do i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571844/discord-py-rewrite-wait-for-how-do-i-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To condense this a little bit, I will use only two of the provided reactions.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Message that's getting reactions")
    paper = '' # for the sake of "I'd rather not copy and paste these emojis a lot"
    hammer = ''
    await message.add_reaction(paper) 
    await message.add_reaction(hammer)

    def check(reaction, user):#checking for reactions and user
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [paper, hammer]
    # in this case, the message author and the reaction emojis paper and hammer

    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 3, check=check)
        # waiting for a reaction to be added
        if str(reaction.emoji) == paper:
            await ctx.send("You reacted!")

        if str(reaction.emoji) == hammer:
            await message.edit(content="Another reaction!")# this is for editing the message sent

    except: # Timeout error-handling
        await message.edit(content="Run command to use again!")
```

If you'd like, you could also include `while True` so the user doesn't have to constantly execute the command.
Working test as seen in the image below:

[image: Code when it works]

---

References:

[discord.Client.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

[discord.Message.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit)

[How to loop with a reaction embed menu (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675404/how-to-loop-with-a-reaction-embed-menu)

Comment: It looks like it works, but It doesn't seem to edit the message for me and gives out no errors

Answer (score 1):

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10.0, check...)
```

If you read the docs about `on_reaction_add`, you'll see that it takes `reaction` and `user` arguments.

To edit the message:

```py
message = reaction.message
await message.edit(content='new content!')
```

Comment: but how can it edit the message that it sends? I don't want it to send a message to the user

Comment: `reaction.message` and simply edit it like any other message

Comment: what needs to be used a check?

def check(reaction, user):return and str(reaction.emoji) == ''


Like that?

Comment: that depends on what are you trying to do

Comment: I just need it to be a check from the author, because I dont want the bot to add the reaction but it changes the message